# How To store Data in a variable and use it in all Application

Tags: c#, winforms, var

I am working on a win form application. I have table(Customer) which will frequently use in all application 
i want to store all customer table Records in a var so I can use it in all application e.g All forms.

```
public  List<Customer> Customers ;
...
     Customers = db.Customer.ToList();
...
```

Please suggest me how can I use this var in other forms?

Thnks

Comment: You pass it when constructing the form.

Comment: @L-Three is there any other way?

Comment: Use static variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a static class that will contain this variable and many other variables that you would like to be accesible from other forms of your application. Something like the below:

```
static class Global
{
    private static List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

    public static List<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return customers; }
        set { customers = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you could access it from every form you want like below:

```
Global.Customers
```

Comment: Why is your property returning a string?

Comment: I'm sure it was a deliberate mistake to check we are paying attention ;)

Comment: @Christos Thanks it works .But i check it without setting get & set method It also work i.e Publicstatic List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>(); then why we need get; set;

Comment: @UmarAbbas yeah it would work alson in this case, I just tried to make it more general, using a getter and a setter, which probably in this case isn't needed. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Make it static:

```
public **static** List<Customer> Customers;
```

Be careful about accessing it from multiple threads though.